# How to set auto-numbering for mail-merged letters?

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I've set up a mail merge to print a standard letter out of a large customer data spreadsheet.

I would like to auto-number each letter thus produced so they each have a unique reference ID.

Initially I thought I could use a print time-stamp, but I can't seem to add any milliseconds to the time-stamp, besides I'm not sure it would work at all.

Is there any way to auto-number the letters?

Answer (score 0):

If your document is a single section - then each document will be in a new section.  You can leverage this fact by inserting a SECTION field (which you can format with # 000000 for example to get 000001, 000002 etc) or even an = FIELD to add a set number to the starting number for this batch so you have cumulative numbering across each batch of mail merges (eg if your last mail merge ended at 1799 and you wanted this run to start at 1800, just use an = FIELD of = { SECTION # 000000} + 1799 }).  After you complete the merge to documents, select all and press F9 to update all the fields and you'll see the SECTION field has then updated.  Interestingly on my computer a SEQ field converted to text at its initial value but the SECTION and = fields remained as field codes.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've tried to figure out what a = FIELD is but I just can't see anything like that in Word. Do you have more info?

Comment: PS: I've found the MERGESEQ field but can't seem to add it up to anything. I've tried { = 80 + MERGESEQ \# 000} but it returns an error.

Comment: The MERGESEQ should also be a field - you don't have the curly field braces in your example so suspect you may have just typed MERGESEQ?  You can edit your field code in your document by pressing SHIFT F9 to view the code, delete the typed MERGESEQ and insert a MERGESEQ field there inside the main formula field.